# QVTKWidget + vtkRectilinearWipeWidget = Visualisation Problem

Tags: qt, vtk

Hallo,

Im trying to use a vtkRectilinearWipeWidget in my Qt Application.

When I create a new vtkRenderWindowInteractor everything works fine and i get a completely working widget in a seperate window. But I want the widget to be within my Application, where i created a qvtkwidget.

The problem is, when i run my application the vtkRectilinearWipe appears, but all the widget features are missing (like the sliders to move the split).

Instead i'm able to rotate the 2D Image with the mouse.

Below I pasted my code (Pastebin alternatively)
I would be really thankful if somebody could take a look at it and maybe figure out what I'm doing wrong.

http://pastebin.com/ufaiyPzv

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that uses a VTK widget in a QVTKWidget: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Qt/BorderWidget